# Negating a custom RSpec matcher that contains expectations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a custom RSpec matcher that checks that a job is scheduled. It's used like so:

`expect { subject }.to schedule_job(TestJob)`

schedule_job.rb:

```
class ScheduleJob
  include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods

  def initialize(job_class)
     @job_class = job_class
  end

  ...

 def matches?(proc)
   job = double
   expect(job_class).to receive(:new).and_return job
   expect(Delayed::Job).to receive(:enqueue).with(job)
   proc.call
   true
 end
```

This works fine for positive matching. But it does not work for negative matching. e.g:

`expect { subject }.not_to schedule_job(TestJob) #does not work`

For the above to work, the `matches?` method needs to return `false` when the expectations are not met. The problem is that even if it returns false, the expectations have been created regardless and so the test fails incorrectly.

Any ideas on how to make something like this work?

Comment: You're not precise when saying `does not work`. AFAIR negated matchers will pass when `matches?` fails. So if at least one of your expectation of `matches?` fails, it's `yes` for negated version. Is this is behavior you're getting, and should you want something else - please update your question.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say `matches?` returns falsey if an expectation set within the `matches?` method itself fails. The negated matcher doesn't work because when the code doesn't schedule the job, the expectations fail e.g.    `expect(job_class).to receive(:new).and_return job` fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to look for it, but I think it's nicely described here in the [rspec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-custom-matcher#matcher-with-separate-logic-for-expect().to-and-expect().not-to)

Format (from the docs) for separate logic when using `expect.not_to`:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :contain do |*expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.all? { |e| actual.include?(e) }
  end

  match_when_negated do |actual|
    expected.none? { |e| actual.include?(e) }
  end
end

RSpec.describe [1, 2, 3] do
  it { is_expected.to contain(1, 2) }
  it { is_expected.not_to contain(4, 5, 6) }

  # deliberate failures
  it { is_expected.to contain(1, 4) }
  it { is_expected.not_to contain(1, 4) }
end
```

Comment: Stackoverflow tends to frown on answers that just link elsewhere. I added the actual answer in for you but so as you know for next time... :)